# build real time API with socket

Tags: html, sockets

I tried to make a static page with socket that show the stocks updates, the page must connect with another socket with this: https://ws-api.iextrading.com/1.0, but it doesn't work

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<h1>hellow world!</h1>


<script>
// server.js
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.emit('message', `A new user, ${Date.now()}, has connected`);
});
</script>

<script>
// public/application.js
socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('You have connected!'); // This will log to the browser's console, not the terminal
});

</script>
<script>
// server.js
io.on('connection', (socket) => {

  socket.emit('message', `A new user, ${Date.now()}, has connected`);

  socket.on('message', (message) => {
    console.log(`The new user's name is ${message.username}, and his message is: ${message.text}`);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('A user has disconnected.');
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the script connecton

```
// Import socket.io with a connection to a channel (i.e. tops)
const socket = require('socket.io-client')('https://ws-api.iextrading.com/1.0/tops')

// Listen to the channel's messages
socket.on('message', message => console.log(message))

// Connect to the channel
socket.on('connect', () => {

  // Subscribe to topics (i.e. appl,fb,aig+)
  socket.emit('subscribe', 'snap,fb,aig+')

  // Unsubscribe from topics (i.e. aig+)
  socket.emit('unsubscribe', 'aig+')
})

// Disconnect from the channel
socket.on('disconnect', () => console.log('Disconnected.'))
```

If anybody know how to connect `socket` please tell me.

Comment: This page is incomplete. Where is the script code that actually creates the websocket object and attempts to connect it to the server? Read [IEX's documentation](https://iextrading.com/developer/docs/#websockets)

Comment: @RemyLebeau because I am new, I don't know how exactly to do and If this service does cost per any request, any help is welcome. Also the the websocket object is not created cause I can't see here to put, maybe up from `const socket`  at the beginning?

Comment: You have shown two separate scripts, but you didn't show how the HTML is invoking the second script, which is the one that actually creates the socket and makes the connection to IEX. Is the second script in a separate `.js` file that the HTML loads? Or is the second script embedded in the HTML? If you expect people to be able to help you, please provide a [mcve] that people can copy/paste and run.

Comment: @RemyLebeau this is the problem, I don't know, how to invoke to html. with the scripts that can connect & creates socket. the .js is separe.

Comment: If your scripts are in separate `.js` files, the HTML needs `<script>` tags that have `src` attributes to refer to those `.js` files.  The HTML you have shown here has `<script>` tags, but they do not have `src` attributes, so the scripts are local to the HTML.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you mean TCP socket you might first learn about [socket connection](http://microchipdeveloper.com/tcpip:use-sockets-to-establish-a-tcp-connection) 
And then to have a web server also you have to download web server ruby

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: This is the wrong answer, and should not have been accepted as such. See https://iextrading.com/developer/docs/, particularly the part about its [WebSockets](https://iextrading.com/developer/docs/#websockets) support.